# How to import Javascript object in xslt script

Tags: javascript, html, xml, xslt

I am using XSLT stylesheet to generate jUnit HTML report which will be sent as an email. Here I want to create Hyperlink in xslt stylesheet and the value of a link is available in the output of javascript "cur['adm-lib']" as mentioned below.

```
 <script type="text/javascript" language="JavaScript">
        var TestCases = new Array();
        var cur;
        <xsl:for-each select="./testsuite">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="properties"/>
        </xsl:for-each>

<xsl:template match="properties">
    cur = TestCases['<xsl:value-of select="../@package"/>.<xsl:value-of select="../@name"/>'] = new Array();
    <xsl:for-each select="property">
    <xsl:sort select="@name"/>
        cur['<xsl:value-of select="@name"/>'] = '<xsl:call-template name="JS-escape"><xsl:with-param name="string" select="@value"/></xsl:call-template>';
    </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:template>
```

Output of above code

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="JavaScript">
        var TestCases = new Array();
        var cur;

    cur = TestCases['com.hyperion.planning.AllJunitTestCase_DTE'] = new Array();

        cur['adm-lib'] = '/scratch/aime1/planning/ADF/Planning/ModelTest/HspAdmDriver/lib';
```

I want to make use of value "cur['adm-lib']" as href in below-mentioned code.

```
<tr>
    <td align="right">Designed for use with <a href="http://www.junit.org">JUnit</a> </td>
</tr>
```

I have tried something like this but its not working

```
 <tr>
    <td align="right">Designed for use with <a <xsl:attribute name="href">javascript:returnHyperlink();</xsl:attribute> >JUnit</a> </td>
 </tr>
```

Can some one please help me with this?

Comment: Isn't this all about the same problem you have raised in earlier questions? As asked there in comments and answers, isn't the problem simply that the targeted email software (Outlook) doesn't execute any Javascript at all in text/html content it receives and renders? If the aim is to use XSLT to transform some XML to HTML links then it seems odd to use Javascript generated by XSLT as an intermediary step. Simply have the XSLT create the HTML links, without throwing in Javascript.

Answer (score 1):

Your XSLT code is generating Javascript code: that part is fine. But until the stylesheet has finished execution, and the generated Javascript is executed, the objects and values created by the Javascript code don't exist yet. The XSLT code therefore can't access any of these JS values.

So your XSLT code can't access the value of `cur['adm-lib']`. It can, however, access data in your original source document: which as far as I can see is simply `@value`.

Comment: Hi Michael - I have updated my code in question. I have created a java script function to return cur['adm-lib']

Comment: <tr>
    <td align="right">Designed for use with <a <xsl:attribute name="href">javascript:returnHyperlink();</xsl:attribute> >JUnit</a> </td>
 </tr>

Comment: Hi Mike  - With better explanation of the issue I have mailed you the details at mike@saxonica.com. I request you to kindly look into it and help me.

Comment: Don't take the discussion offline. Firstly, it's important for other people that if it reaches a conclusion, the whole discussion should be archived here. Secondly, people like me do StackOverflow work at a much lower level of priority than answering emails.

Comment: Thanks for correcting me :) . I request you to let me guide me towards solution